# How to extract cornerCoordinates with python and after convert to latlong?

Tags: python, gdal, convert, coordinates, latitude-longitude

I need extract metadata from file .tiff but specifically I need get corner coordinates, and after convert this to lat-long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to use the `osgeo` module, specifically `gdal`. Below is a sample:

```
from osgeo import gdal

ds = gdal.Open("my_tiff.tif")
x = ds.GetGeoTransform()[0]
y = ds.GetGeoTransform()[3]
```

This returns the coordinate of the top left corner of the top left pixel.

It would depend on what georeferencing is used in your tiff file to convert to Lat/Lon. If it is in utm, for example, you could use the `utm` module's `utm.from_latlon(lat, lon)`. To convert the coordinates.

Comment: You have a mistake in y coordinate. It's `y = ds.GetGeoTransform()[3]`. Please, see http://www.gdal.org/gdal_tutorial.html.

Answer (score 3):

Other way is using `rasterio` module for getting coordinates, and `pyproj` module for converting them. Example:

```
import rasterio
import pyproj

my_file = rasterio.open('file.tif')
bounbox = my_file.bounds
my_proj = pyproj.Proj("+init=epsg:5514")#your data crs

left_bottom = my_proj(bounbox[0],bounbox[1], inverse=True)
right_top = my_proj(bounbox[2],bounbox[3], inverse=True)
```

Comment: Can you please post some example?

Comment: In my answer is example. I have data ('file.tif') in EPSG:5514 CRS, after runnig this code I get the corner coordinates (lat-long) in WGS